# Getting "Permission denied" when trying to create a file despite correct permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, touch, amazon

I’m using Amazon Linux and running a script through a Jenkins job, including this line

```
touch /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/myproject.war.dodeploy
```

which results in the error …

```
touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/myproject.war.dodeploy’: Permission denied
```

I thought I had the perms and groups set properly, so I output those in my script as well.  But I can’t see why things are falling apart.  Below is the output.  What else do I need to do to get my touch command to work?

```
+ whoami
jboss

+ groups jboss
jboss : jboss evotext

+ ls -al /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  4 deploy evotext 4096 Apr 23 18:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 jboss  evotext 4096 Jun 24  2013 ..
drwxrwxr-x 11 jboss  evotext 4096 Apr 23 18:23 myproject.war
drwxrwxr-x  9 deploy evotext 4096 Apr 22 19:21 jenkins.war
-rwxrwxr-x  1 deploy evotext   11 Apr 22 19:21 jenkins.war.deployed

+ touch /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/myproject.war.dodeploy
touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/myproject.war.dodeploy’: Permission denied

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: All looks okay. Did you log out and log back in since joining the group `evotext` (hint: use `id`, not `groups jboss` to check which groups you are *really* a member of)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the parent directory has acl's that are preventing you from editing it?
 Try doing this command:

```
sudo setfacl yourname:rwx /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments
```

Where yourname is your username.